# A simpler if/elseif/else logic?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements, markup

This is the grid markup that I need to employ (for displaying 5 highlighted posts):

```
<div id="top-stories" class="row">

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <article><!-- first article content --></article>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <article><!-- (normal) article content --></article>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <article><!-- (normal) content --></article>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <article><!-- (normal) content --></article>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <article><!-- (normal) content --></article>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, the markup around each post is different; which means I need to use an if/elseif/else logic to dynamically show posts in this markup.

This is how I am doing it right now (notice that the posts are in a loop):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $current_post_count = post_count(); ?>
    <div id="top-stories" class="row">
      <?php if( 0 == $current_post_count ) { ?>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <article><?php echo $first_article_content; ?></article>
        </div>

      <?php } elseif( 1 == $current_post_count ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>

      <?php } elseif( 2 == $current_post_count ) { ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>
      <?php } elseif( 3 == $current_post_count ) { ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>

      <?php } elseif( 4 == $current_post_count ) { ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is, the code isn't very precise. I couldn't figure out a better logic so far. How can I rewrite the dynamic code to make it more optimal and precise?

Comment: You seem to repeat 2 and 3? And a bit of 1 and 4 aswell?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wny do you need an `if(have_posts())` around `while(have_posts())`? If there are no posts, the `while` will terminate immediately.

Comment: @putvande 1 is entirely different from the rest. 2, 3, and 4 have some code in common.

Comment: Instead of a series of `if/then/elseif` on the same variable, use `switch()`.

Comment: I was just about to suggest using a switch($current_post_count)

Comment: If they're the same, why not use `||` to combine them into one `if`?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35930/a-simpler-if-elseif-else-logic

Comment: @Barmar as you can see in the question, while they (2,3,4) have **some** code in common, it's their wrappers that make it difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this combines the common parts of 2,3,4 best:

```
<?php switch ($current_post_count) {
case 0: ?>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <article><?php echo $first_article_content; ?></article>
</div>

<?php break;
case 1: ?>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
</div>

<?php break;
default: ?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
</div>
<?php switch ($current_post_count) {
    case 2: ?>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>
        <?php break;
    case 4: ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
} ?>
```

Comment: Learnt something today. Thank you very much for [suggesting a better approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149145/a-simpler-if-elseif-else-logic#comment30032386_20149441) (`switch`) and showing a better logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $current_post_count = post_count(); ?>
    <div id="top-stories" class="row">
      <?php switch($current_post_count ): 
      case 0: ?>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <article><?php echo $first_article_content; ?></article>
        </div>
      <?php break;?>
      <?php case 1: ?>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>
      <?php break;?>
      <?php case 2: ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>
      <?php break;?>
      <?php case 3: ?>
      <?php case 4: ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <article><?php echo $article_content; ?></article>
            </div>
      <?php break;?>
      <?php endswitch;?>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why use `switch` when the code is along as what I am using now?

Comment: Length isn't the only criteria, clarity is important. `switch` makes it clear that every case depends on the same variable, while `if/then/elseif` can perform different tests in each case.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, I agree. But the main idea of the question is to know if there's a better logic that I can employ? Something I haven't figured out.

Comment: @its_me I think the logic  is simple enough, but it is important to make it clear

Comment: I don't think this logic is the same as the OP. In the original code, the extra `</div>` lines are part of case 4, not both 3 and 4.

Comment: @Barmar that's right and **switch** can handle some unknown case with a default option